# Homebrew httpd error - Error: Failure while executing

Tags: apache, homebrew

Can someone shed some light onto what's happening with my homebrew installation?

I'm trying to install PHP as per: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-multiple-php-versions

When I run

```
brew services restart httpd
```

I get:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/nigelbrewer/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 5.
```

I've googled but can't to seem to find a solution?